# Set Two Keys on an Object

Tags: javascript

I have an object **$scope.int.views** and I want to set two new objects, one to each other like:

```
$scope.int.views[key][$scope.data.year] = {};
```

But this does not work, because **$scope.int.views[key]** is undefined. The best way I know how to do this is like:

```
$scope.int.views[key] = {}, $scope.int.views[key][$scope.data.year] = {};
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: EWRONGSYNTAX: Expected ":" after "$scope.". "`$scope.data.year`" is not a valid key name. Further, the TO probably wants the key to be named by the value "`year`" has.

Comment: The way in your question is the simplest. Shorter doesn't mean simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
($scope.int.views[key] = {})[$scope.data.year] = {};
```